# Android - get session from webview and set it in httpclient

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

I have an app that runs a webview, and an image uploader is written in native Android. When user logs in the webview and tries to upload image using httpclient, my backend server won't recognize who it is. How can I grab the session from webview and set it to httpclient then execute?

Thanks

Comment: Depends how you authenticate user, but you have a fair change to simply read cookies from webview and pass them to httpclient.

Comment: thats exactly what I want to do!! but I can only find how people grab cookies from httpclient then pass to webview, cant find the solution for the other way around.

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Comment: how can I set the cookie to httpclient? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request) but still not working...

Comment: another thing is....after I got the cookies from `CookieManager.getCookie(url);` , I cant set the cookie to `CookieStore` because `getCookie` returns a `String` not `Cookie`

Comment: Working example here at `loadUserProfile` https://gist.github.com/arpit/610754

Comment: everything looks right...but im still not able to get it work. is there a test domain that I can try to see if my session really got passed? I feel like my session isnt passed...