# How to use HttpClient to keep login state for furture process after the app was restarted?

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

My app use HttpPost to login a discuss so I can get some pages that must need to be loged in used the same httpClient instance .
But if my app was quit and restart again after sometime. Can I use the httpClient response that keep me the state that I have loged in?
If can't,what should I do when the app quit?
save the cookie?
Or can I save the httpClient instance?
How to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Is that the Client that restarts or the Server?
If the Client restarts you only need t save the cookies on the client side and reuse them (set cookie expiry to far future).
If Server restarts you need to save sessions (in DB?) and restore them when Server starts.

Comment: the Client restart.So when the app quit.I save the cookie.And when the app start, I use the cookie I saved to set HttpClient ?so I can use the httpClient for further purposes?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Could you give me some information about how to get cookie from httpclient and how to save the cookie and when i get the cookie from file, how to set the httpclient used the cookie.Thank you.I searched that question but a got little useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is save the user's data to the `PreferenceManager` when the user login for the first time and when the app quit and then restarted you can then check the `PreferenceManager` if it have some data or not before you do some action.

[click here](http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/) for more info about PreferenceManager and how to do it.

Comment: OK,thank you.So i have to re-login if the PreferenceManager has userdata when the app restart?

Comment: @leizh007 yes.. if it is not there then go back to login page

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is save your session cookie (probably JSESSIONID).

When your app goes down just write in some file (like session.txt) or even serialize some class with this information. And when your app starts, check if this file exists, get the session id from it, delete the file, and set the session cookie in your HttpClient.

Comment: Ok,thank you.So when the app quit.I save the cookie.And when the app start, I use the cookie I saved to set HttpClient ?so I can use the httpClient for further purposes?

Comment: Yes, here is an answer how you should configure a cookie in HttpClient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request