# HttpRequestHandler - How to tell client to save a cookie?

Tags: java, apache, http

I'm in a journey of making a simple `HTTP` server using Java for educational purposes. I need to know how to instruct a client to save a cookie for identifying its session ID.

I've done my research and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request) which, despite being greatly informative and in fact introduced me to the whole `CookieStore` thing, does not really specify how to tell the client to save a cookie.

From what I've come to understand, the `handle` method in `HttpRequestHandlers` has only three parameter passed to it:

- `HttpRequest` - the request itself along with some information about it.
- `HttpResponse` - the "medium" as of where the response should be writen upon.
- `HttpContext` - ... (Not really sure what it does, TBH.)

Meanwhile, all of the answers in the links I've stated above would call

- `response = client.execute(httppost, localContext);`, or
- `HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(method1, httpContext);`

..at some point of the handling. I've no idea on how one could get a reference to the client (and thus execute the request to store the cookie).

What should I do? Am I missing something?

Comment: When your's server gives response to client's request, you must include cookie headers (like, `Set-Cookie: value;path;domain;expire`) in that response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("Name","Value");
userCookie.setMaxAge(-1);//for a session cookie
userCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(userCookie);//adds to cookie to the response that is sent to the browser.
```

Comment: This would seem like it. I'm going to give it a go when I got home and verify if it indeed answer my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry but after I tried it, the `addCookie` method only available in `HttpServletResponse` and not in `HttpResponse` I'm currently using.

Comment: Interesting.  You are going to need to add a "Set-Cookie:"  element to your response headers.  What library are you using for the HttpResponse object?

Comment: I'm going through with Apache at the moment. Perhaps it's important to notice that I'm working on Android. So I think Apache is the only way to go.

Comment: Looking at that library, HttpResponse extends HttpMessage.  HttpMessage manipulates the header.  Try something like response.addHeader("Set-Cookie","value;path;domain;expire);

Comment: I guess that'll do! Was hoping for a more sophisticated solution but after spending some time scouring the docs it seems like the only way to go. Thanks for pointing it out for me. :)